# Yield symbol (chemistry)

Tags: symbols, arrows, characters

I'm trying to format a chemical reaction with LaTeX, and apparently it doesn't accept "→" as a character. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Usually such an arrow is created using `\to` in mathmode which is also accessible as `\rightarrow`. [Dexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) also lists `\textrightarrow` (for text mode), `\shortrightarrow` and `\longrightarrow`.

Using the right settings you should also be able to use `→` as an unicode character directly. This, however, depends also on the used compiler (PDFLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX).

You should however consider to use a dedicated package for chemical reaction, for example [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem). There is also [`chemarrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemarrow) which provides arrows for chemical reactions, but it seems a little outdated (2001). For more LaTeX packages about chemistry see the [list on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=chemistry&search_type=description).